# Driver qsql para arquitectura ARM

Tags: sql, qt, arm

tengo un problema el cuál es que al compilar una aplicación con toolchains a una Tarjeta con Yocto Linux no consigo conectar con la base de datos ya que el driver qsqlite no se encentra en la tarjeta y no hay otros drivers disponibles, éste es el error que sale en pantalla de debug

```
QSqlDatabase: QSQLITE driver not loaded
QSqlDatabase: available drivers: 
QSqlQuery::prepare: database not open
```

quisiera saber si alguien tiene conocimientos de este error.

En mi archivo .pro tengo

```
QT += sql
```

Answer (score 0):

Por defecto Qt se presenta como librerías externas (DLLs). Para que tu ejecutable pueda hacer uso de ese driver es necesario llevar la DLL correspondiente junto con tu ejecutable.

Para saber qué dependencias son necesarias es mejor que le eches un vistazo a esta  [guía](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/deployment.html) (es demasiado extensa como para comentarla en la respuesta).